# Can not install libltdl-dev:i386 on ubuntu 14.04.1 x64

Tags: 14.04

```
xhadesvn@zoo:/home/tlbb/Server$ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libltdl-dev:i386
Suggested packages:
  libtool-doc:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libltdl-dev:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/157 kB of archives.
After this operation, 924 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 46588 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libltdl-dev_2.4.2-1.7ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libltdl-dev:i386 (2.4.2-1.7ubuntu1) ......................................] 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libltdl-dev_2.4.2-1.7ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/libtool/libltdl/Makefile.in', which is different from other instances of package libltdl-dev:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libltdl-dev_2.4.2-1.7ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I recived that error when trying to install libltdl-dev x86

I 've google for that error but didnt get the fix docs.

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deb package is corrupted. You can simply remove the corrupted package with `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libltdl-dev_2.4.2-1.7ubuntu1_i386.deb` and attempt to reinstall. The package you are looking for can be found [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libltdl-dev)
and you can download and install it via the Software Center (or your favorite package installer) or after removing the offending package you can simply

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libltdl-dev
```

Comment: thanks for help, i 've to also del /usr/share/libtool/libltdl/Makefile.in file, now it work.